# Releasing instance of Fragment without UI when setRetainInstance(true)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, orientation

I need to add a row to my SQLiteDatabase and as a result i want to obtain newly created ID of the row. I extended AsyncTask class in order to run this task in the background thread, here it is:

```
private class InsertLangTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            if (mDB.isOpen()) {
                try {
                    mId = mDB.insertOrThrow(DBS.D.TN, null, mCV);
                }
                catch (SQLException e) {
                    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
                    query.append("SELECT " + BaseColumns._ID + " FROM " + DBS.D.TN + " WHERE ");
                    Object[] bindArgs = new Object[mCV.size()];
                    int i = 0;
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: mCV.valueSet()) {
                        query.append((i > 0) ? " AND " : "");
                        query.append(entry.getKey());
                        query.append(" = ?");
                        bindArgs[i++] = entry.getValue();
                    }

                    SQLiteStatement statement = mDB.compileStatement(query.toString());

                    for (i = 0; i < bindArgs.length; i++) {
                        DatabaseUtils.bindObjectToProgram(statement, i + 1, bindArgs[i]);
                    }

                    try {
                        mId = statement.simpleQueryForLong();
                    } finally {
                        statement.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (mActivity != null) { mActivity.onLangInserted(mId); }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

This InsertLangTask class is enclosed in Fragment class where i implements only onCreate(), onAttach() and onDetach(), also i create a method inside to initialize members (cannot do it in constructor, as it must be empty in Fragment classes). I wrap AsyncTask in this Fragment class in order to preserve my mId member and pass it back to my activity even if the configuration was changed and activity was destroyed. I know that it's not exactly the case of long-term operation, but it can possibly be. Here are the parts of this class:

```
public class InsertLangFragment extends Fragment {

public static interface OnLangInsertedListener {
        void onLangInserted(long id);
    }

SQLiteDatabase mDB = null;
ContentValues mCV = null;

private OnLangInsertedListener mActivity = null;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mActivity = activity;
}

public void RunTask(SQLiteDatabase db, ContentValues cv) {
    new InsertLangTask().execute();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mActivity = null;
}
}
```

And in my Activity i just write this when i want to start this process:

```
InsertLangFragment fragment = new InsertLangFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragment, "insertTaskFragment").commit();
fragment.RunTask(mSQLiteDatabase, mContentValues);
```

Obtaining mId in implemented callback

```
public void onLangInserted(long id) {

}
```

I used setRetainInstance(true) so this fragment will never be destroyed (except back button) and will be located in memory all time. The question is how should i properly destroy fragment instance?  I suppose that i have three possible outcomes:
1) It's not necessary to destroy this Fragments.
2) I should put getFragmentManager().remove("insertTaskFragment").commit() at the end of onLangInserted() in my Activity
3) I should put setRetainInstance(false) at the end of onPostExecute() in AsyncTask.

Please give me an advice how should i manage this Fragment properly.
  Thank you. Please don't be too strict, i'm a newbie here.

Comment: I am afraid it is nearly impossible to figure out what you are asking here. It's extremely difficult to understand without paragraphs or code formatting.